# Accessing Raycaster Members

Tags: aframe, webvr

In my scene I'm using a script to create an entity with a raycaster component. This works great, and the event listeners are working fine colliding with my ground object. But my ground is uneven, and I need to know the height of the ground where the raycaster hits. As far as I know, this isn't possible with just what A-Frame provides. I'd like to call THREE's raycaster.intersectObject, but I'm not able to get a working reference to the THREE raycaster. The A-Frame documentation mentions a member called raycaster, but it's undefined for me. I've tried a few different things, but to no avail. My next plan was to make a new component, but I figured I'd ask here first.

```
var ray = document.createElement('a-entity');
ray.setAttribute('id', 'raycaster');
ray.setAttribute('raycaster', 'objects: #ground');
ray.setAttribute('position', pos);
ray.setAttribute('rotation', '-90 0 0');
scene.appendChild(ray);

var ground = document.querySelector('#ground');

ray.addEventListener('raycaster-intersection', function() {
    console.log(ray.raycaster);         //undefined
    console.log(ray.intersectedEls);    //undefined
    console.log(ray.objects);           //undefined
    console.log(ray.object3D.id);       //gives me the THREE id
    console.log(ray.object3D.intersectObject(ground.object3D, false));  //intersectObject not a function
});
```

Any clues? I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a member of the component, which you'll have to dig for.

`ray.components.raycaster.raycaster`

- `ray` - entity
- `.components` - the entity's components
- `.raycaster` - the raycaster component
- `.raycaster` - the raycaster object as a member of the raycaster component

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete component in case anyone is interested. Just add "set-to-ground" to your entity. If you want objects to be standing on the ground, you can add them as children to the entity and set their relative y position to half the object height.

Should still be enhanced with a "target" selector though as currently the ground needs to be with id 'ground'

```
        AFRAME.registerComponent('set-to-ground', {
            schema: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            init: function () {
                var data = this.data;
                var el = this.el;
                var scene = document.getElementById('ascene');
                var ray = document.createElement('a-entity');
                ray.setAttribute('id', 'raycaster');
                ray.setAttribute('raycaster', 'objects: #ground');
                ray.setAttribute('rotation', '-90 0 0');
                el.appendChild(ray);

                var ground = document.querySelector('#ground');

                ray.addEventListener('raycaster-intersection', function getY() {
                    console.log(ray.components.raycaster.raycaster.intersectObject(ground.object3D, true)[0].point.y); //groundPos to log
                    var groundPos = ray.components.raycaster.raycaster.intersectObject(ground.object3D, true)[0].point.y;
                    ray.removeEventListener('raycaster-intersection', getY);
                    el.setAttribute('position', {y: groundPos});
                });

            }
        });
```